# Como voltar a página anterior com os dados do form utilizando o codeigniter

Tags: php, css

Boa tarde utilizando o codeigniter como faço para voltar pára a página anterior sem perder os dados do form? esses dados vieram de um controller e passados por parametros a uma view, quando eu acesso outra página e clico em voltar a página não volta fica em branco a tela.

```
$data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
$this->load->view('cadastro', $data);
```

Eu entro na parte de cadastro e clico em alterar, e antes de alterar o cadastro se eu clicar em voltar (botao) ela não retorna a página de cadastro, já add caminho em $route['cadastro'] mas mesmo assim sem sucesso.